# Unable to install selenium using (pip install -U selenium) in command prompt

Tags: python, selenium, pip

I am a newbie to Python_Selenium. I have installed python and done below Environment setup :

> OS =  Windows7
>
> Python 2.7.13
>
> Java = Java7

While entering `pip install -U selenium` and hitting enter in command prompt getting below error.

> Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None))
>   after connection broken by
>   'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out.
>   (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/selenium/

Cab any body please help ?

Comment: Connection to pypi.python.org timed out.

Comment: Does https://pypi.python.org/pypi come up in a browser from the machine you're `pip install`'ing from?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using proxy to access this website from browser, you need to change your command to reflect this proxy server as well.

```
pip install -U selenium --proxy=<proxy address>
```